# Identify magnitude of each spectrum obtained through spectogram in Python

Tags: python, signal-processing, spectrogram, waterfall

I am currently plotting a specgram using python matplotlib as shown below:
Pxx, freqs, bins, im=ax.specgram(data, NFFT=1024, Fs=fs, mode='psd', cmap='plasma',sides='twosided')
I am to generate a waterfall plot using this with varying magnitude:
[image]

However, can anyone direct me on how to extract time and frequency points corresponding to those points which has higher magnitude(the portion in yellow section).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try to apply peak detection to each frame of your NFFT data by looping. [Scipy](https://github.com/MonsieurV/py-findpeaks#scipysignalfind_peaks) has the algorithm for peak detection. Or you can use a simple baseline parameter for the yellow part value to compare if the corresponding data exceed the yellow part.